# ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_font_cache' failed

Tags: embedded-linux

I am getting following error while building image using `bitbake core-image-minimal` tool.

```
ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The postinstall intercept
hook 'update_font_cache' failed, details in
/home/santhosh/Denverton/Source/BSP/poky/build/tmp/work/ddsmdnv-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
/home/santhosh/Denverton/Source/BSP/poky/build/tmp/work/ddsmdnv-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.4876
ERROR: Task
(/home/santhosh/Denverton/Source/BSP/poky/meta-ddsmdnv/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs)
failed with exit code '1' NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3901 tasks of
which 3886 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:  
/home/santhosh/Denverton/Source/BSP/poky/meta-ddsmdnv/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit
code.
```

Could you please help me how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run `bitbake -v core-image-minimal` and inspect around last line which "The postinstall intercept hook" appeared. I had experienced this error too but on different postinst-intercepts scripts.

Comment: Probably is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841836/yocto-postinstall-intercept-hook-update-desktop-database-error/

Answer (score 0):

It is a wired error, sometimes cleaning the the `build` directory (especially `sstate-cache` folder) will help.